# Django: unique constraint with a DESC order index

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add a unique constraint with a desc index.
I can create a desc index on two fields like that :

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['some_field', '-date']),
    ]
```

And I can create a unique constraint like this :

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=('some_field', 'date',),
            name='core_message_uniq_mmsi_time'
        )
    ]
```

This will create a unique index, but the order won't be the good one and for some reason using a `'-date'` in the `UniqueConstraint` does not seem to do the trick.

Is there something I'm missing, or is it required to have two indexes, one with the unique constraint and another one with the correct order ?

Thanks !

Comment: No, `UniqueConstraint` doesn't accept the `-`. So to get the ordered index, you'll have to define it separately indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.0/#functional-unique-constraints), you can create a unique constraint with [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/constraints/#expressions).

I believe you could update your code with something like this:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            'some_field', F('date').desc(),
            name='core_message_uniq_mmsi_time'
        )
    ]
```