# Proper way to access latest row for each individual identifier?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `core_message` in Postgres, with ***millions*** of rows that looks like this (simplified):

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│    Colonne     │           Type           │ Collationnement │ NULL-able │                Par défaut                │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ id             │ integer                  │                 │ not null  │ nextval('core_message_id_seq'::regclass) │
│ mmsi           │ integer                  │                 │ not null  │                                          │
│ time           │ timestamp with time zone │                 │ not null  │                                          │
│ point          │ geography(Point,4326)    │                 │           │                                          │
└────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
Index:
    "core_message_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "core_message_uniq_mmsi_time" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (mmsi, "time")
    "core_messag_mmsi_b36d69_idx" btree (mmsi, "time" DESC)
    "core_message_point_id" gist (point)
```

The `mmsi` column is a unique identifier used to identify ships in the world. I'm trying to get the latest row for each `mmsi`.

I can get that like this, for example:

```
SELECT a.* FROM core_message a
JOIN  (SELECT mmsi, max(time) AS time FROM core_message GROUP BY mmsi) b
       ON a.mmsi=b.mmsi and a.time=b.time;
```

But this is too slow, 2 seconds+.

So my solution was to create a distinct table containing only the latest rows (**100K+ rows max**) of the `core_message` table, called `LatestMessage`.

This table is populated via my application every time new rows have to be added to `core_message`.

It worked fine, I'm able to access the table in a matter of milliseconds.
But I'd be curious to know if there is a better way to achieve that using only one table and keep the same level of performance for data access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse While this answer in itself does not solve my case, one of the answer referenced a way to solve my problem. I will post an answer here for my particular case using that way.

Comment: There is some good information. It also matters how many *millions* of rows there are and how many distinct `mmsi` exactly (*100K+ rows max`?). And some other details - [as instructed here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/4122419) seems to go in the way of the `DISTINCT ON` answer here, however it also mentions this :

> For ***many* rows per customer** (low cardinality in column
>   `customer`), a [**loose index scan**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) (a.k.a. "skip scan") would be
>   (much) more efficient, but that's not implemented up to Postgres 12.
>   (An implementation for index-only scans is in development for Postgres
>   13. See [here](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/19/1741/) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/707b6f68-16fa-7aa7-96e5-eeb4865e6a30@redhat.com).)
>   For now, there are **faster query techniques** to substitute for this.
>   In particular if you have a
>   separate table holding unique customers, which is the typical use
>   case. But also if you don't:
>
> - **[Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)**

Using this [other great answer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/707b6f68-16fa-7aa7-96e5-eeb4865e6a30@redhat.com), I find a way to keep the same performance as a distinct table with the use of `LATERAL`.
By using a new table `test_boats` I can do something like this :

```
 CREATE TABLE test_boats AS (select distinct on (mmsi) mmsi from core_message);
```

This table creation take 40+ seconds which is pretty similar to the time taken by the other answer here.

Then, with the help of `LATERAL` :

```
SELECT a.mmsi, b.time
FROM test_boats a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT b.time
    FROM core_message b
    WHERE a.mmsi = b.mmsi
    ORDER BY b.time DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b LIMIT 10;
```

This is blazingly fast, 1+ millisecond.

This will need the modification of my program's logic and the use of a query a bit more complex but I think I can live with that.

For a fast solution without the need to create a new table, check out the
answer of @ErwinBrandstetter [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57965560/4122419)

---

**UPDATE:** I feel this question is not quite answered yet, as it's not very clear why the other solutions proposed perform poorly here.

I tried the benchmark mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/4122419). At first, it would seem that the `DISTINCT ON` way is fast enough if you do a request like the one proposed in the benchmark : +/- 30ms on my computer.
But this is because that request uses [index only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html). If you include a field that is not in the index, `some_column` in the case of the benchmark, the performance will drop to +/- 100ms.

Not a dramatic drop in performance yet.
That is why we need a benchmark with a bigger data set. Something similar to my case : 40K customers and 8M rows. [Here](https://gist.github.com/FractalWire/aaef90e893590260dd03ddf54b542ca9)

Let's try again the `DISTINCT ON` with this new table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id) id, customer_id, total 
FROM purchases_more 
ORDER BY customer_id, total DESC, id;
```

This takes about 1.5 seconds to complete.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id) *
FROM purchases_more 
ORDER BY customer_id, total DESC, id;
```

This takes about 35 seconds to complete.

Now, to come back to my first solution above. It is using an index only scan and a `LIMIT`, that's one of the reason why it is extremely fast. If I recraft that query to not use index-only scan and dump the limit :

```
SELECT b.*
FROM test_boats a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT b.*
    FROM core_message b
    WHERE a.mmsi = b.mmsi
    ORDER BY b.time DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b;
```

This will take about 500ms, which is still pretty fast.

For a more in-depth benchmark of sort, see my other answer [below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975451/4122419)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick performance comparison for the queries mention in this post.

**Current setup :**

The table `core_message` has 10,904,283 rows and there is 60,740 rows in `test_boats` (or 60,740 distinct mmsi in `core_message`).

And I'm using PostgreSQL 11.5

**Query using index-only scan :**

1) using `DISTINCT ON` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mmsi) mmsi 
FROM core_message;
```

2) using `RECURSIVE` with `LATERAL`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT mmsi
   FROM   core_message
   ORDER  BY mmsi
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT mmsi
      FROM   core_message
      WHERE  mmsi > c.mmsi
      ORDER  BY mmsi
      LIMIT  1
      ) m
   )
TABLE cte;
```

3) Using an extra table with `LATERAL`:

```
SELECT a.mmsi
FROM test_boats a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT b.time
    FROM core_message b
    WHERE a.mmsi = b.mmsi
    ORDER BY b.time DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b;
```

**Query not using index-only scan :**

4) using `DISTINCT ON` with `mmsi,time DESC` `INDEX`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mmsi) * 
FROM core_message 
ORDER BY mmsi, time desc;
```

5) using `DISTINCT ON` with backward `mmsi,time` `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mmsi) * 
FROM core_message 
ORDER BY mmsi desc, time desc;
```

6) using `RECURSIVE` with `LATERAL` and `mmsi,time DESC` `INDEX`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   core_message
   ORDER  BY mmsi , time DESC 
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT *
      FROM   core_message
      WHERE  mmsi > c.mmsi
      ORDER  BY mmsi , time DESC 
      LIMIT  1
      ) m
   )
TABLE cte;
```

7) using `RECURSIVE` with `LATERAL` and backward `mmsi,time` `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (

   (

   SELECT *
   FROM   core_message
   ORDER  BY mmsi DESC , time DESC 
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT *
      FROM   core_message
      WHERE  mmsi < c.mmsi
      ORDER  BY mmsi DESC , time DESC 
      LIMIT  1
      ) m
   )
TABLE cte;
```

8) Using an extra table with `LATERAL`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM test_boats a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT b.*
    FROM core_message b
    WHERE a.mmsi = b.mmsi
    ORDER BY b.time DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b;
```

**Using a dedicated table for the last message:**

9) Here is my initial solution, using a distinct table with only the last message. This table is populated as new messages arrive but could also be created like so :

```
CREATE TABLE core_shipinfos AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
       (
       SELECT *
       FROM   core_message
       ORDER  BY mmsi DESC , time DESC 
       LIMIT  1
       )
       UNION ALL
       SELECT m.*
       FROM   cte c
       CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
          SELECT *
          FROM   core_message
          WHERE  mmsi < c.mmsi
          ORDER  BY mmsi DESC , time DESC 
          LIMIT  1
          ) m
       )
    TABLE cte);
```

Then the request to get the latest message is as simple as that :

```
SELECT * FROM core_shipinfos;
```

**Results :**

Average of multiple query (around 5 for the fast one):

1) 9146 ms 
2) 728 ms 
3) 498 ms

4) 51488 ms 
5) 54764 ms 
6) 729 ms 
7) 778 ms 
8) 516 ms

9) 15 ms

**Conclusion:**

I won't comment on the dedicated table solution, and will keep that for the end.

The additional table (`test_boats`) solution is definitely the winner here but the `RECURSIVE` solution is also pretty efficient.

There is a huge gap in performance for the `DISTINCT ON` using index-only scan and the one not using it but, the performance gain is rather small for the other efficient query.

This makes sense as the major improvement those queries bring is the fact that they don't need to loop over the whole `core_message` table but only on a subset of the unique `mmsi` that is significantly smaller (60K+) in comparison to the `core_message` table size (10M+)

As an additional note, there does not seem to be significant improvement in performance for the queries using the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` if I drop the `mmsi,time DESC` `INDEX`. But dropping that index will of course save me some space (this index currently take 328MB)

**About the dedicated table solution:**

Each messages stored in the `core_message` table carries both positional informations (position, speed, heading,etc.) AND ship informations (name, callsign, dimensions, etc.), as well as ship identifier (mmsi).

To give a bit more background on what I'm actually trying to do : I'm implementing a backend to store messages emitted by ships via the [AIS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system).

As such, every unique mmsi I got, I got it via this protocol. It is not a pre-defined list. It keeps adding new MMSI until I got every ships in the world using AIS.

In that context, a dedicated table with ship informations as last message received makes sense.

I could avoid using such a table as we've seen with the `RECURSIVE` solution, but... a dedicated table is still 50x faster than this `RECURSIVE` solution.

That dedicated table is in fact similar to the `test_boat` table, with more information than just the `mmsi` field. As it is, having a table with `mmsi` only field or a table with every last informations of the `core_message` table add the same complexity to my application.

In the end, I think I will go for this dedicated table. It will gives me unbeatable speed and I'll still have the possibility to use the `LATERAL` trick on `core_message`, which will gives me more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Results agree with my experience. The dedicated table including the latest time is essentially a materialized view (MV) solution, where `SELECT` is expected to be very fast in comparison. Typically, ships move around constantly, producing a constant stream of new rows for core_message. Keeping the MV current means an extra `UPDATE` for every `INSERT`, roughly doubling the write cost. A simple table of unique ships is much cheaper, 1 `INSERT` for every new ship. You'll have weigh total costs against the faster `SELECT`. Whichever is worth more to you should win ..

Comment: BTW, removing the dupe index was not meant to improve the `SELECT` speed. It improves write speed and saves storage and added `VACUUM` cost.

Comment: I added a link to your new benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860).

Comment: `SELECT` on the latest message is definitely the top priority here. This will probably be about 90% of the queries done by the user and I want that to be as fast as possible. 15 ms essentially means that the database response will be negligeable beside network response time, for example. Currently, I use a buffer before inserting into the database, so it's not exacly real-time, but near real-time. For a buffer of 15 min worth of data, or about 250K rows, it took 1 min to insert all. On that 1 min, about 1 sec is used to insert rows in the `MV`, and the rest for the insert in `core_message`...

Comment: I believe that is due to two things: 1) I only insert the latest messages of the buffer in that `MV` (only 30K rows). 2) the indexing probably took most of the insert time for the `core_message` table. In any case, 15:1 min is not so bad for my use case but I might try to optimized that later as 250K rows for 1 min seems rather slow.

Comment: In any case, I think I learnt a lot with that question. Thx a lot for your answers here and on the other part of SO, it definitely helped me !

Answer (score 2):

You have put existing answers to good use and came up with great solutions [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895730/939860). Some missing pieces:

> I'm still trying to understand how to properly use his first `RECURSIVE` solution ...

You used this query to create the `test_boats` table with unique `mmsi`:

```
select distinct on (mmsi) mmsi from core_message
```

For ***many*** rows per boat (`mmsi`), use this faster **`RECURSIVE` solution** instead:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT mmsi
   FROM   core_message
   ORDER  BY mmsi
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT mmsi
      FROM   core_message
      WHERE  mmsi > c.mmsi
      ORDER  BY mmsi
      LIMIT  1
      ) m
   )
TABLE cte;
```

This hardly gets any slower with more rows per boat, as opposed to `DISTINCT ON` which is typically faster with only few rows per boat. Each only needs an index with `mmsi` as leading column to be fast.

If possible, create that `boats` table and add a FK constraint to it. (Means you have to maintain it.) Then you can go on using the optimal `LATERAL` query you have in your answer and never miss any boats. (Orphaned boats may be worth tracking / removing in the long run.)

Else, another iteration of that `RECURSIVE` query is the **next best thing** to get whole rows for the latest position of each boat quickly:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   core_message
   ORDER  BY mmsi DESC, time DESC  -- see below
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT *
      FROM   core_message
      WHERE  mmsi < c.mmsi
      ORDER  BY mmsi DESC, time DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) m
   )
TABLE cte;
```

You have both of these **indexes**:

```
"core_message_uniq_mmsi_time" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (mmsi, "time")
"core_messag_mmsi_b36d69_idx" btree (mmsi, "time" DESC)
```

A `UNIQUE` constraint is implemented with all columns in default `ASC` sort order. That cannot be changed. If you don't actually need the constraint, you might replace it with a `UNIQUE` *index*, mostly achieving the same. But there you can add any sort order you like. Related:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

But there is no need for the use case at hand. Postgres can scan a b-tree index backwards at practically the same speed. And I see nothing here that would require *inverted* sort order for the two columns. The additional index `core_messag_mmsi_b36d69_idx` is expensive dead freight - *unless* you have other use cases that *actually* need it. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)

To best use the index `core_message_uniq_mmsi_time` from the `UNIQUE` constraint I step through *both* columns in descending order. That matters.

Comment: I would be interested how the queries perform in your test setup - also after you drop the redundant index.

Comment: Thx for clarifying how this `recursive` works, and pointing the fact that I don't need another `index` with the `unique` constraint. As my index does not use `NULL LAST`, I had to remove those part in your query otherwise, the query never stopped. I will put a quick note regarding the performance of the queries.

Comment: @ogr: Ah, right. No `NULLS LAST` here. That was misplaced, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I recommend `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mmsi) m.*
FROM core_message m
ORDER BY mmsi, time DESC;
```

For best performance, you want an index on `(mmsi, time desc)`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that way before, unfortunately, it is actually worse than my request : 40+ seconds. and I already have an index on (mmsi, time desc). But I also have an unique index on (mmsi, time). This is mandatory, because I'm using Django, and it seems the ORM doesn't provide a way to index on a tuple with the DESC order : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874365/django-unique-constraint-with-a-desc-order-index

Comment: @ogr . . . I am really surprised this is 20X slower than your version.  `DISTINCT ON` usually has better performance than alternatives.

Comment: Having dig a bit more on other similar issue, this comment seems to confirm that `DISTINCT ON` is slower on large table : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group#comment34434519_7630564 My table has currently 8.652.526 rows

Comment: @ogr . . . I don't think that comment is accurate; `distinct on` *does* use indexes.  Follow Erwin's links to a more comprehensive benchmark on Postgres 9.4 and 9.5.  He doesn't even consider doing a `JOIN` -- and from what I know of him, that is not a mistake, it is because he knows those would be slower.

Comment: turned out you were right, I first tried to bump his benchmark with a dataset that would match mine [here](https://gist.github.com/FractalWire/aaef90e893590260dd03ddf54b542ca9). And for a moment, I thought the issue was there, but... it turns out the real problem is in the `*` in my request. The slow part here may be the loading time in memory of all the field. If you limit those field or use the `LIMIT` clause, it is very fast. Note that other methods like the one mentionned in my answer are still faster with the `*`. So, not sure why that is exactly...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `ROW_NUMBER()`, which is widely supported across RDBMS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM core_message c
) AS cr WHERE rn = 1
```

This query should benefit of existing index `core_messag_mmsi_b36d69_idx`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has the same performance as the solution proposed by @gordonlinoff, 40+ seconds